# What is the exact value range for unsigned long?

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned

I am working through the exercises in the book "Learn C the hard way". Exercise 7 asks the reader to find the value which makes the range of an `unsigned long` exceed.

> Change `long` to `unsigned long` and try to find the number that makes it too big.

So my approach is to first get the size of an `unsigned long` on my machine:

```
printf("SIZEOF ULONG: %lu", sizeof(unsigned long));
```

This prints `8` as a result. So assuming that an `unsigned long` will take up 64 bits on my machine I looked up the maximum range on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).

64-Bits (word, doubleword, longword, long long, quad, quadword, qword, int64)

- Unsigned: From 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

I was expecting that declaring an `unsigned long` with the above value would compile without warnings until I increment the value by 1. The result is different though. compiling the following program results in a warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615;
    printf("SIZEOF ULONG: %lu", sizeof(unsigned long));
    printf("VALUE: %lu", value);
    return 0;
}

bla.c: In function ‘main’:
bla.c:5:27: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
     unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So why does gcc complain about the value being to large, I thought I already declared it as `unsigned`?

Comment: You declared the variable's type, but not the value.

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` and use `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: Aside: you should use `%zu` format specifier for type `size_t` not `%lu`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Decimal integer constants have type `int` if they fit in that range, otherwise they have type `long` or `long long`.  They do not have an unsigned type, and if the value is outside those signed ranges you get the warning. You need to add the `ul` suffix for the constant to have the proper type.

There’s also a much easier way to get the maximum value of this type without knowing its size.  Just cast -1 to this type.

```
unsigned long value = (unsigned long)-1;
```

Comment: Saying unsuffixed integer constants have type `int` by default gives short shrift to the hierarchy of types they have, which depend on their values and whether they are decimal or octal/hexadecimal.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Agreed.  Updates to better reflect the constant type rules.

Comment: The `l` suffix seems unnecessary. `u` or `U` should suffice to silence the warning.

Answer (score 5):

You need a suffix for the integer literal for values than won't fit in a long int (or long long int, since C99 and C++11).  Any of the following will comply for unsigned long int:

```
unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615u;
unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615lu;
unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615ul;
```

Please see the suffix table here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant (for C)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal (for C++)

Comment: @chqrlie - Thank you, missed that.  Updated with references for C.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler processes `unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615;` in several steps. Before it can initialize `value` with a value, it has to read `18446744073709551615` from the source code and interpret it.

The numeral `18446744073709551615` in source code stands on its own—it is not immediately affected by the fact that, in a moment, it will be used to initialize `value`. It is processed according to rules in the C standard.

These rules say that a numeral with decimal digits and no suffix is either an `int`, a `long int`, or a `long long int`, whichever is the first that can represent the value. Since 18446744073709551615 is so big, it does not fit into any of these types.

The compiler is warning you that, since 18446744073709551615 does not fit into any of these types, it is using an unsigned type for it. In other circumstances, this could change the meaning of the code. However, in this case, since the value is immediately used to initialize an `unsigned long`, it will have the desired effect.

To remedy this, you can add a `u` suffix, changing it to `18446744073709551615u`. For a decimal numeral suffixed with `u`, the C standard says the type is the first of `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, or `unsigned long long int` that can represent the value.

(The C standard goes on to say that, if a value is too big for the listed types, the C implementation can represent it with an extended integer type or that it has no type. The consequences of having no type might be interesting to explore, but that is a subject for a language-lawyer question.)

Answer (score 0):

use `unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615ul;` else `18446744073709551615ul` is read as an *int* not as a *long*

If you want to know the number of bits in an *unsigned long* and the max value :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("number of bits in ULONG: %d\nULONG_MAX = %lu\n",
       sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT,
       ULONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra u.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
number of bits in ULONG: 32
ULONG_MAX = 4294967295
```

Yes my long are not on 64bits

Comment: `18446744073709551615ul` is not “managed” as an `int`, nor is its type `int`. Nor would `18446744073709551615` have type `int` in OP’s implementation, nor would any integer constant exceeding `INT_MAX` have type `int`.

Comment: The text in this answer says ”`18446744073709551615ul` is read as an int not as a long”. That is false. Per C 2018 6.4.4.1 5, it is an `unsigned long int`, an `unsigned long long int`, or is an extended type or, if not representable in any of those, has no type. It is not an `int` or a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

The integer constant `18446744073709551615` is too large to be represented as an `int`, `long int` or `long long int` on your system. The compiler warns you about the fact that it makes it an `unsigned long long`.

Let's try and compile this program instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (-1 < 18446744073709551615)
        printf("TRUE\n");
    else
        printf("FALSE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

`gcc` does issue the warning:

```
#1 with x86-64 gcc 8.2
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:7:14: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
     if (-1 < 18446744073709551615)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the program output is this:

```
TRUE
```

`clang` generates a more explicit warning:

```
#1 with x86-64 clang 7.0.0
<source>:7:14: warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]
    if (-1 < 18446744073709551615)
             ^
```

But the program output is:

```
FALSE
```

If `18446744073709551615` is indeed interpreted as unsigned, as if written `18446744073709551615u` or `0xffffffffffffffff`, the comparison must be performed using unsigned arithmetics and fails because both numbers have the same value. `clang` does what it says, but `gcc` does not.

In your case, storing the value into an `unsigned long` variable should produce the expected result, but adding a `u` suffix to the constant will ensure that it is parsed by the compiler with the correct type.

Note however that you can obtain the maximum value of any unsigned type by casting `-1` to that type. You can also use the macros defined in `<limits.h>`: the maximum value for type `unsigned long` is `ULONG_MAX`.