# The program gives wrong answer for large input

Tags: arrays, c, sum

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.
> (the input are the five elements of the array `arr`)

```
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int *arr) 
{ 
    unsigned long int sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, max, min;
    int i;
    sum1 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    sum2 = arr[4] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    sum3 = arr[0] + arr[4] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    sum4 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[4] + arr[3];
    sum5 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[4];
    min = max = sum1;
    unsigned long int sumall[5] = { sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5 };
    for (i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) {
        if (sumall[i] >= max) {
            max = sumall[i];
        } else if (sumall[i] <= min) {
            min = sumall[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%lu %lu", min, max);
}
```

the above function gives output

```
2063136757 18446744072159051663
```

for the input

```
256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071624
```

Comment: What is the value of `ULONG_MAX` on your system? See [C and C++ Integer Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-170) and [What is the exact value range for unsigned long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813967/what-is-the-exact-value-range-for-unsigned-long)

Comment: I think you just need sumof5 - min and sumof5 - max.

Comment: BTW, your loop can start at `i=1`, since you already used `sumall[0]` when initializing `min` and `max`.

Comment: Try just printing all the values in `sumall`.

Comment: The largest and smallest sum can be found in a single pass, just by finding the largest and smallest elements. The largest sum is found by dropping the smallest element, and the smallest sum is found by dropping the largest element.

Comment: OT: `arr_count` is redundant when the array of values contains `5` elements and always will... Rename the function to `miniMaxSum5()` please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `int` addition which risks signed integer overflow (*undefined behavior* (UB)), perform wider addition.

```
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int* arr) { 
  unsigned long int sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, max, min;
  ...
  sum1=arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3];
  //   ^ int addition w/int sum  ^

  sum1 = 0UL + arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
  //     ^ unsigned long addition with unsigned long sum ^
```

Even better, as `long` may not be wider, use `long long` and stay with *signed* types:

```
  long long sum1 = 0LL + arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
  //               ^ long long addition w/long long sum  ^
  ...
  printf("%lld %lld",min,max);
```

---

**Curious way to find min/max**

OP's min/max search loop the finds the man/max of the 5 sums.  Notice the max exceeds `INT_MAX` for OP.

2,063,136,757
2,744,467,343

The sum of all 5 minus max sum in then the the min value of the 5 original.
The sum of all 5 minus min sum in then the the max value of the 5 original.

938,071,624
256,741,038

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get invalid output is some of the sums exceed the range of type `int`, eg: `arr[4] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3]` causes a signed integer overflow which has undefined behavior. Storing the result into an `unsigned long` variable does not fix the problem as the overflow has already occurred.

You must compute the sums using a larger type, such as `long long int` on most platforms.

Also note that the output is specified as a **line**, hence must include a trailing newline.

Note that you can simplify the problem by computing the minimum and maximum values in the array:

```
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int *arr) 
{ 
    long long int sum = 0, min = 0, max = 0;

    if (arr_count > 0) {
        sum = min = max = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr_count; i++) {
            long long int val = arr[i];
            if (max < val)
                max = val;
            if (min > val)
                min = val;
            sum += val;
        }
    }
    printf("%llu %llu\n", sum - max, sum - min);
}
```